# Reverse columns in using sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

If i have a file like this:

```
aa:bb:cc  
dd:ee:ff
```

I want to reverse the columns to this:

```
cc bb aa  
ff ee dd
```

Basically reversing the columns and replacing the ":" with a " "

Ive been just trying to get the reversing down before worrying about the ":" replacement. Im trying to use only sed for this.

```
sed -r 's/(:.*)(.*:)/\2\1/'
```

Ideally this should match everything up to the first ":" then match everything after the last ":" then print them in reverse order but thats not the case.

Any help would be nice, i feel like im close but just missing something here.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist using sed:

```
sed -r ':a;/[^:]*:[^:]*:/{s/([^:]*):([^:]*):(.*)/\2 \1:\3/;ba};/[^:]*:[^:]*$/s/([^:]*):([^:]*)$/\2 \1/;' file
```

little loop there.

But use awk is better:

```
awk -F: '{for(i=NF;i>1;i--)printf("%s ",$i);print $1}' file
```

printf won't return(plus \n), print would.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what is going on in that sed command? Im new so its got me a bit lost.

Comment: POW used the right word here: "If you _insist_". Providing the `sed` solution was just being [overly] kind. `sed` is the _wrong_ tool for this job. Notice how simple the `awk` solution is and that it will work even if you had 100 fields/line. The `sed` regex is _hardwired_ for three. Imagine how complex it gets for [say] nine or more. Half the battle is picking the right tool/methodology at the outset. If you need to understand the `sed` version, you'll need to break it down yourself as it's far too complex for an explanation here.

Comment: I think `a:b:c:d` should be converted to `d b c a` and not `d c b a`.

Answer (score 1):

awk really is the better tool for this, but if you are restricting yourself to 3 columns, a reasonable way to use sed is:

```
$ k='\([^:]*\)'
$ sed "s/$k:$k:$k/\3 \2 \1/" input
```

Comment: The modularized expression certainly adds to the readability. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/$/:\n/;ta;:a;s/^([^ :]+)\s*:(.*\n)/\2 \1/;ta;s/\n //' file
```

This appends a newline and another delimiter (`:`) to the end of the line. Then moves the first column to just after the newline and prepends a new delimiter () to it. This is repeated until the first character of the line is a newline which is then removed along with the unwanted extra new delimiter.

N.B. The `ta` command following the first substitution is there to reset the truth flag because the first substitution will always succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: this should match everything up to the first ":" then match everything after the last ":" then print them in reverse order. I think you want `aa:bb:cc:dd` converted into `dd bb cc aa`. This can be done with

```
sed -e "s/^\([^:]*\):\(.*\):\([^:]*\)$/\3 \2 \1/" -e 's/:/ /g' inputfile
# Test
echo "aa:bb:cc
aa:bb:cc:dd" | sed -e "s/^\([^:]*\):\(.*\):\([^:]*\)$/\3 \2 \1/" -e 's/:/ /g'
# Output
cc bb aa
dd bb cc aa
```

Explanation: `^` matches start of line, `$`end-of line. `[^:]*` matches a string without a `:`. `\(some_match\)` remembers `some_match`, which can be shown with `\1` (1 is the first thing in memory).